# VBA - find replace using arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, replace, find

I am trying to do multiple replaces into a list of texts (which are also stored in an array):

```
'Create an array to include the find & Replace Lists
FindReplaceLists = Worksheets("FRLists").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

'Create an Array for the data to be replaced
TotalRows = Worksheets("testing").Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
myArray = Worksheets("testing").Range(Cells(1, 8), Cells(TotalRows, 8)).Value

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(FindReplaceLists, 1) To UBound(FindReplaceLists, 1)
    'Loop through each cell in Question Label make the substitution
      For y = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
        myArray(y, 1) = Replace(myArray(y, 1), FindReplaceLists(x, 2), FindReplaceLists(x, 3))
        Debug.Print myArray(y, 1)
      Next y
  Next x
```

The replacements should be partial - the texts to find are part of the texts in myArray.
But no changes are done to the elements of my array. Am I mis-using the replace function, or am I mis-using the arrays?

Comment: If you want the replacement to be case-insenstive may be you should set the parameter `Compare:=vbTextCompare` ?

Comment: @A.S.H that is true, but does not help - the text substutitions are not being done, regardless of the `compare` setting. And in th example I am working on, the text to be replaced are identical to the ones to be found

Comment: I see. Well I dont see any error in the code. Just make sure you're not reversing the two arguments `Find` and `Replace`?

Comment: When you say the replacements are not being done, do you mean in the `Debug.Print` or on the worksheet?

Comment: Actually @A.S.H 's comment does it; I was looking at the old results... If you  will formulate it as an answer, I will accept it; @Comintern : I was referring to `Debug.print` :)